# How to increase bone size?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, edit-mode

The bones on an armature are way too small and I can barely see them, even with the "in front" option toggled. I tried scaling the bones but scaling them all together moves them out of place since they don't share the same origin. Is there an easy way to increase the size of al of the bones?
Note: The bones are in octahedral model.

Comment: enable Pivot Point > Individual Origin?

Comment: Scale the object. Apply the scale.

Comment: You mean this is to have a custom view of bones so that they are easier to see?

Comment: You can switch pivot point to individual origins to scale multiple objects about their own origins simultaneously.  You can also look into the use of custom shapes for bones to change the way they're displayed without changing the way they behave.